# Get those elements from a List of custom class objects whose one property value is parseable to double

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list, collections

I have a list of custom class objects in C# with class structure like this:

```
public class ABC
{
   int ID;
   string Text1;
   string Text2;
}
```

This list stores data like this:

```
+-----+-------+--------+
| ID  | Text1 |  Text2 |
+----------------------+
| 1   | PQR   |  test1 |
|     |       |        |
| 2   | XYZ   |  12.69 |
+-----+-------+--------+
```

I am trying to get rows with distinct `ID` like this:

```
ABCObject = ABCObject.GroupBy(c => c.ID).Select(c => c.First()).ToList();
```

It's working fine. But, I want to add another condition that `ABCObject` should contain only those rows that have `double` data. In above given case it's row with `ID = 2`. So, is it possible to do this in LINQ? Or I have to create another function that will run a `foreach` loop and test each element using `double.TryParse()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `double.TryParse` within LINQ, although admittedly the `out` parameter is annoying:

```
ABCObject = ABCObject
    .Where(x => { double ignored; return double.TryParse(x => x.Text2, out ignored); }
    .GroupBy(c => c.ID)
    .Select(c => c.First())
    .ToList();
```

You could make this cleaner with your own reusable method which uses nullable types instead of bool+out to return the result:

```
private static double? NullableTryParseDouble(string text)
{
    double result;
    return double.TryParse(text, out result) ? result : default(double?);
}
```

Then:

```
ABCObject = ABCObject
    .Where(x => NullableTryParseDouble(x.Text2) != null)
    .GroupBy(c => c.ID)
    .Select(c => c.First())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: That was really a neat solution. Specially that reusable method. Thanks a lot. :)